# Assigning Variable to Range of Numbers with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, variables, range

I have a simple problem (I hope). I've got an input form that takes, as input, 2 numbers, a start (`$tag_start_01`) and an end value (`$tag_end_01`).

I want to generate a string of numbers between those inputs, and assign them to a new variable (`$tag_range_01`), so that I can write the string to a TXT file.

The foundation of the code here, works:

```
foreach (range($tag_start_01, $tag_end_01, 1) as $tag_range_01) {
    echo "$tag_range_01, ";
}
```

This will generate (assuming **start** is 1 and **end** is 10):

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
```

How do I assign this resulting set of numbers to the variable `$tag_range_01` as a string?

Comment: `$tag_range_01 = implode(', ',range($tag_start_01, $tag_end_01, 1))`. Without `foreach`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it without using `foreach` loop :

```
$tag_range_01 = implode(', ',range($tag_start_01, $tag_end_01, 1));
```